# Booting from USB and not installing

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I created a live usb to boot Kubuntu, which has worked well enough. However, when the installation gets to the point of telling me to restart the computer (and it restarts) the installation window pops up again, and the computer is still signed in as a live user. None of the installation or settings appear to have saved.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure Secure Boot is turned off in the BIOS settings and make sure you booted the USB in (U)EFI mode.

Comment: @ElderGeek check the top answer. OP did that.

Comment: @ElderGeek Ah OK.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you attempting to install?

Comment: The latest one, 16.something

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output  of `sudo fdisk -l`  (You can open a terminal from your live media to enter the command)

Answer (score 1):

Eject your usb drive and restart. It looks like it is booting to your drive instead of the Harddisk.

Comment: I just tried this. The computer doesn't boot at all, instead going to Dell device scanner. Going into the boot menu didn't work either, as it has no options for which order the computer should boot in.

Comment: Help me understand, you created a live usb and then installed the os on what device the usb or the hdd?

Comment: I created the live USB, then attempted to boot it. Kubuntu walked me through the installation process

Comment: But where was your destination for the installation? the usb or the internal HDD?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. Where can I find this?

Comment: When you ran the install, did it install to /dev/sda or /dev/sdb?

Comment: It says /dev/sdb/.

Comment: go to the terminal and type in this command and give us the output:

`lshw -short -C disk`

Comment: If it says command not found then type this instead: `sudo apt-get install -y lshw && sudo lshw -short -C disk`

Comment: What should I do if it actually says /dev/sda ?

Comment: please refer to my last comment so that we can know your drive scheme. it will tell us who is sda and who is sdb. so that we can better help you.

Comment: It is sda. I read something incorrectly, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not suere when to eject the USB after the installation, hit F12 or F2 when the computer restarts (whichever is BIOS boot option) and select Hard drive after that restart.

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed to the USB instead of HDD. Remove the USB drive, then boot your computer normally and see if Ubuntu comes.

Comment: Additionally, what computer is this? Maybe there is something weird with the BIOS (or the computer is UEFI).

Comment: It's a Dell Inspiron, previously running Windows 10

Comment: Does it USe UEFI?

Comment: Not sure, I'm kind of new at this, sorry

Comment: No problem. Just give me the model name and I'll check.

Comment: It seems that some of the Dell Inspirons do use UEFI instead of the traditional BIOS.